# What does " turning cartwheels down" mean in the text below?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

*Occasionally they sang softly; occasionally they **turned cartwheels down** by the moving streak of phosphorescence.*

Comment: No one *turned cartwheels down*, they did that *down by the moving streak*.

Answer (score 3):

'Down' is linked to 'by', not to the cartwheels: they *turned cartwheels* **down by** the phosphorescence. In other words, they *performed circular sideways handsprings* ([as Lexico defines cartwheels](https://www.lexico.com/definition/cartwheel)) **beside** the moving streak of phosphorescence.